# Rxjs - Call promise and observable sequentially

Tags: javascript, http, promise, rxjs, observable

I want to call a function that will return a promise and then pass the result to another function that will return an observable. I need to do this sequentially and get the final result as an observable so I can subscribe.

For example:

```
// Call a function and return a Promise
myPromise() {}

// Make an http call and return an Observable
myObservable() {}

// Call myPromise() then call myObservable() and return
// an Observable with the result
// *I don't know how this function should be*
myFunction() {}

// Subscription
myFunction().subscribe(
  result => console.log(result),
  error => console.log(error),
  () => console.log('completed'));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you have trouble with? Maybe I misunderstood your question, it seems pretty straightforward. `promiseReturningFunction().then(observableReturningFunction).subscribe(observer)` and before calling `promiseReturningFunction`, make sure it is the first time it is called. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have any code samples so that we can help you?

Comment: Do not need to call just once, forget about it. I edited the question with a small sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
let stream$ = Observable.defer(() => Observable.fromPromise(myPromise()))
    .flatMap(promiseResult => myObservable(promiseResult));

stream$.subscribe(obsResult => console.log(obsResult));
```

The `.defer` is needed to ensure that your promise-method is called with every subscribe, and not just once during initialization.

Comment: Just add a .catch(...) after the flatMap that will handle any previouse error

Comment: ...or you just  use the second argument in your .subscribe, that will also receive any thrown errors